# Using a custom web server for sharing Anchor IDs doesn't work

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm trying to use my own Python cgi script to store and serve Anchor IDs. Everything worked with the Swagger Sharing Server from the samples repository but somehow when I switch to my Python server I get an Error and the app is stuck looking for the anchor.

What I'm doing is, I assume, exactly the same the Swagger Script does: I send the Anchor ID to the server and return an Anchor number to be able to request the ID later again.
As far as I understood the ID needs to be exchanged as a string and that's what I return from my Python server as well (Content-type: text/plain).

However I get following error on my Android when trying to parse the key / look for the Anchor ID once I got it from the server:

Here's the relevant error message from logcat:

```
04-29 07:33:01.031: I/Unity(28756): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
04-29 07:33:02.062: I/Unity(28756): State from DemoStepLookForAnchor to DemoStepLookingForAnchor
04-29 07:33:02.062: I/Unity(28756):  
04-29 07:33:02.062: I/Unity(28756): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
04-29 07:33:02.141: E/Unity(28756): InvalidOperationException: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target. Request CV: . Response CV: .
04-29 07:33:02.141: E/Unity(28756):   at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.NativeLibraryHelpers.CheckStatus (System.IntPtr handle, Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.status value) [0x000cc] in <b52d7a321113460294136f243fd7bd66>:0 
04-29 07:33:02.141: E/Unity(28756):   at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.CloudSpatialAnchorSession.CreateWatcher (Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.AnchorLocateCriteria criteria) [0x00019] in <b52d7a321113460294136f243fd7bd66>:0 
04-29 07:33:02.141: E/Unity(28756):   at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Samples.AzureSpatialAnchorsDemoWrapper.CreateWatcher () [0x00008] in <b52d7a321113460294136f243fd7bd66>:0 
04-29 07:33:02.141: E/Unity(28756):   at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Samples.AzureSpatialAnchorsSharedAnchorDemoScript.AdvanceLocateFlowDemo () [0x00090] in <b52d7a321113460294136f243fd7bd66>:0 
04-29 07:33:02.141: E/Unity(28756):   at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.Samples.AzureSpatialAnchorsSharedAnchorDemoScript.AdvanceDemo () [0x00018] in <b52d7a321113460294136f243fd7bd66>:0 
04-29 07:33:02.141: E/Unity(28756):   at Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.Unity.
```

What could be wrong?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That error message “bad lexical cast” likely means that you created a watcher with was an invalid anchor ID. Have you tested your server (with Postman or something like it) to make sure it’s returning IDs?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, as I've checked the returning IDs in the log, they both look the same. When using the Python server:  `05-16 00:05:09.152: I/Unity(4290): Found key 1242713e-2538-4cfa-a47f-79f806047996`when using the swagger server:  
`05-16 09:54:15.261: I/Unity(15678): Found key 6e523d9c-709c-49df-ad2d-7a3de07fa3cb`

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sure! Here you can find the updated AnchorExchanger.cs: https://pastebin.com/rpnYvJ9V you can see the edits where the "myServer" boolean gets queried. This is the python server: https://pastebin.com/bynCfh85 . Apart from that I've only changed the BaseSharingUrl check in AzureSpatialAnchorsSharedAnchorDemoScript.cs. Thank you very much for looking into this!

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: I finally found the problem(s)! The issue was my half knowledge of Python: Apart from using an unreliable database (anydbm is much better) I made the mistake to output the Anchor ID string via `print` which adds a line-break at the end and thus invalidates the Anchor ID. Using `sys.stdout.write` now and it works perfectly. Sorry for bothering you with this completely Azure/Unity unrelated issue.

Comment: I am glad you were able to find the issue. Would you please mark this as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[JanLa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11434776/janla) answers in a comment:

> The issue was my half knowledge of Python: Apart from using an unreliable database (anydbm is much better) I made the mistake to output the Anchor ID string via `print` which adds a line-break at the end and thus invalidates the Anchor ID. Using `sys.stdout.write` now and it works perfectly.