# Using own server to store Azure Cloud Anchor IDs

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I want to store/retrieve the Cloud Anchor IDs to my own server instead of using Swagger.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929296/using-a-custom-web-server-for-sharing-anchor-ids-doesnt-work) post and what this gentleman is doing is creating his own server, I do not want to to do that. I simply want to store the Cloud Anchor ID's to my own server(I am of course using the Azure Cloud Anchor service account ID and Key for the service itself).

I have script that will upload and receive from my server but I don't know where to inject that code in the Azure Spatial Anchors Demo (v1.3.2) and where else to make changes(I have removed the BaseSharingURL checks in the AzureSpatialAnchorsSharedAnchorDemoScript.cs)

**Update 1:**

Thanks to BroConnly I have managed to edit the "*StoreAnchorKey*" method in the *AnchorExchnger.cs* and can successfully store the anchor key.

However, now, the retrieval of that is an issue. I have tried making changes to the RetrieveAnchorKey and RetrieveLastAnchorKey to the best of my knowledge. [`Here`](https://pastebin.com/zb5S7Pdv) is the script, please have a look and tell me where I am wrong be cause my debug console logs "Failed to retrieve last anchor key"

I am also attaching the [`AzureSpatialAnchorsSharedAnchorDemoScript`](https://pastebin.com/xp6dYA67).cs script, I have made only small changes likes removing BAseShare URL checks and instantiate my own server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script named `AnchorExchanger.cs` contain a class called `AnchorExchanger` in the AzureSpatialAnchorPlugin (reference: [AnchorExchanger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/blob/master/Unity/Assets/AzureSpatialAnchors.Examples/Scripts/AnchorExchanger.cs)). You can replace this script with your own.

Comment: thank you!! I figured out how to store, could you look over my post again and guide me on how to retrieve please? thanks

Comment: have you tried to access your rest api in a browser when you access the retrievelastanchorkey function? when I check your code you seems to return value of return is `return IDgotten + "/last";` which the output is obviously the anchor ID combined with the string "/last". I think you should try access the swagger first. their database contain at least (int) id and (string) anchorid, so when you find anchor id number, they will return (string) anchorid.

Comment: actually, that's not the point. when the console log return "Failed to retrieve last anchor key", the problem is in your `myServerScript.getID` is unable to retrieve the data.

Comment: yes but I can't figure out where or what exactly is the problem with mySerScrupt.getID

Comment: I'm sorry but that's clearly the problem in your personal script `myServerScript.getID` on function `getID()`. You can refer to the original `AnchorExchanger.cs` on how to retrieve the data. they request to retrieve anchor with int `id number` or string `last` as as passing parameter. your structure database should at least have that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough knowledge even if you sent me all your code. I think the best way is to test your Id retrieval script first before implement it in the azure spatial anchor. If you can store the ID, then it should be easy for you to retrieve the data. All I can say is the relationship between the database and azure spatial anchor is to retrieve in format `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`. After the data retrieved you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/how-tos/create-locate-anchors-unity#locate-a-cloud-spatial-anchor)

Comment: if you can retrieve the data correctly, I can help you to get the azure spatial anchor. by referring to the link I previously sent you.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I got curious when you told about the format of the anchor ID and made a test script to actually check if it is being uploaded to my back-end or not and it turns out I was getting a false positive all along. I have now been able to upload successfully, now I just need to retrieve it and can't figure out where the magic of retrieval and then putting the game object in scene is happening

Comment: now I am stuck at this, I enter the saved anchor key but I get this on logcat adb 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/67L2KvV)

Comment: can you print / log your retrieved anchor id? The only thing you need to change is AnchorExchanger script. The error log shows, that you're still unable to retrieve the data in correct way. Also, you should be able to trace back by looking at the log. You got error between the state `DemoStepLookForAnchor` and `DemoStepLookingForAnchor`. Specifically, `the anchor Identifier you give is invalid`. mean, you're still unable to return the anchor Id value correctly.

Comment: check your return value of the `RetrieveAnchorKey` and `RetrieveLastAnchorKey` in your `AnchorExchanger` Script once again.

Comment: I can't directly change stuff in the 'AnchorExchanger' since my backend server must run on the main thread & has problems with async. Even with uploading to my server, I created a new script that in it's own lifecycle uploads the AnchorKey. [This](https://pastebin.com/Q1bSksDf) is that new script, [this](https://pastebin.com/m8dZq4h1) is where it's called in the 'AzureSpatialAnchorSharedAnchorDemoScript', and [this](https://pastebin.com/rRUL0c3Y) is the AnchorExchanger code itself, where anchor is stored, as you can see, I am only returning the key to keep the program running happy.

Comment: yes, as I said. Your ID Storing step doesn't seem to have any problem, the problem lies in your return value for retrieval. when you run the Application, it stopped and got error [logcat adb](https://imgur.com/a/67L2KvV). The error stopped in Anchor retrieval part. which is why I told you to check your retrieval code. I asked you to check your return value for `RetrieveAnchorKey`

Comment: thank you again for your input! I have managed to retrieve and locate the anchor! however, it only happens once. when I run the demo again just to locate the same anchor my app crashes and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you check what kind of error you get? and which state did your app crash? as I have said, the logcat adb is pretty useful for debugging. so you better check up on that. Judging from your code, I can only guess you use a file handling as database, your apps crash maybe because you didn't handle the file handling properly.

Comment: I hope you can mark this question as solved. thanks

Comment: @Newbzz  have u stored anchor id in ur  own db and server and im also facing the same issue im not sure how to save this data in to my own server and in couchdb